# How to access hovered country names of a plotly/chloropleth map. Is there a getter-like way to do this?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

this might be a total dumb question but I fail to access some fields of a plotly object in python. So far I just worked with java a lot and my new university wants me to code some python stuff, where I am stuck probably cuz of my java-way of thinking.

## Question:

How to access internal fields of a plotly/chloropleth map?

## Code Example:

first I import plotly express and create a plotly world map which i want to use later to select a country

```
import plotly.express as px
gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
mapfig = px.scatter_geo(gapminder,
                    locations="iso_alpha",
                    hover_name="country",
                    size="pop")
```

later I visualize the figure via a html

```
html.Div(
    dcc.Graph(
        id='country-selector',
        figure=mapfig,
    )
)
```

when I run the python script now I see a worldmap and I am able to hover over any country seeing a popup with the population and the countires name. so far so good. now to the problem: i cant access the country names / or hover_name later in my code when  I try to update other graphs.

## What I imagine it to look like:

```
html.Div(
    dcc.Graph(
        id='country-selector',
        figure=mapfig,
        hover_name=  --> here i need some kind of java style getter on the hover_name of mapfig
    )
)

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('graph-indicator-1', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('country-selector', 'hover_name')])

def update_other_graph(hover_name, selected_value_for_indicator_1):

--> here i want to work with hover_name (the name of the hovered country of my world map)
```

Maybe someone a little more skilled than I am with python and plotly knows the answer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the country name from the `hoverData` like this:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px

app = dash.Dash()

gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
mapfig = px.scatter_geo(gapminder,
                        locations="iso_alpha",
                        hover_name="country",
                        size="pop")
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='country-selector',
        figure=mapfig,
    ),
], className="container")

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('country-selector', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('country-selector', 'hoverData')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('country-selector', 'figure')]
)
def drawStockPrice(hover_data, figure):
    data = figure['data']
    layout = figure['layout']

    if hover_data is not None:
        print('Country:', hover_data['points'][0]['hovertext'])

    return {'data': data, 'layout': layout}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```